# Segfault when calling Gtkmm textBuffer->insert

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, gtkmm

I'm just learning about gtkmm for c++.
I'm having trouble getting a simple TextBuffer to add a new line of text.
I have a class called OutputBox which is an HBox with a TextViewer (called messages) and a TextBuffer (called textBuffer) in it.

Here is a small chunck of the OutputBox class:

```
OutputBox::OutputBox() {
  textBuffer = messages.get_buffer();
};

void OutputBox::addText( string newText) {
  textBuffer->insert(textBuffer->begin(), newText);
};
```

Now I expect that when I pass a string into addText, the new string will be added to the buffer, but instead I get a seg fault.

After running it through gdb, I see that the error comes from the gtkmm libraries here:

```
template <class T_CppObject> inline
T_CppObject* RefPtr<T_CppObject>::operator->() const
{
  return pCppObject_;
}
```

I'm not really sure what this is telling me either.  I assume that I'm incorrectly using the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise attaching a **debugger** to see where the fault occurs.

If it occurs within GTKmm libraries, then you are *probably* using the API incorrectly. If it occurs in your code then it will point you in the right direction

:)